# How do I check which version of groovy is with which version of grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I download grails 2.2.1. I want to check which version of groovy this comes with?
How do I this?

Comment: GRAILS_FOLDER\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [grails shell](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/shell.html) to launch an interactive Groovy console within Grails and identify the version.

```
$ grails shell

Groovy Shell (2.0.8, JVM: 1.7.0_21)
Type 'help' or 'h' for help.
-----------------------------------
groovy:000>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it's possible to find the Groovy version of grails looking for the versions of the files in the folder depending on the version:

```
[GRAILS_FOLDER]/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars
```

or

```
[GRAILS_FOLDER]/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars
```